# How to measuring cluster health of openstack swift

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I know there are built-in tools `swift-dispersion-populate` and `swift-dispersion-report` that  measure swift cluster health. `swift-dispersion-report` samples 1% of all partitions to compute the health of cluster.

My question is that are there other efficient approaches rather that sampling  to monitor swift cluster health?

Answer (score 1):

- [https://github.com/Dieterbe/graph-explorer](https://github.com/Dieterbe/graph-explorer%20%28graphite%20dashboard%29) Graph Explorer
- https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/Diamond Diamond

Dimond is a python daemon that collects system metrics and publishes them to Graphite (and others). It is capable of collecting cpu, memory, network, i/o, load and disk metrics. Additionally, it features an API for implementing custom collectors for gathering metrics from almost any source. It can be integrated with Swift

Hope it helps.